# Any way to get required substitute values from template using Freemarker?

Tags: java, freemarker

Using https://freemarker.apache.org/

Is there any way to get the names of the values that template is going to substitute (without trying to process template with empty data and parse exception message).

Eg.

TemplateVal:

```
{
  "k1": "${val-to-sub-1}",
  "k2": "${val-to-sub-2}"
}
```

Freemarker(TemplateVal).getValsToSub() -> ["val-to-sub-1", "val-to-sub-2"]